# Software Installation Error in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

My Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS and when I am installing any external softwares like `Meld` in my Ubuntu it is giving the error:

```
E: The package uno-libs3 needs to be reinstalled
```

but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before installation? This package, uno-libs3, can be installed from the standard repository.

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: Uno-libs3 is a referred package for Libreoffice. You could try to install it, downloading [deb file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libs/uno-libs3) or reinstall LibreOffice.